# Quasar error when audion HTML 5 Audio Tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue js Quasar framework, I am encountering a problem when I add this html 5 element

```
<audio name="test" ref="player" id="player" controls>
                    <source v-bind:src="track">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
```

I suddenly encounter this error

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '1' is not a valid attribute name."
>
> DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '1' is not a valid attribute name.

Can someone point me in the right direction what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of "track" ?